# Linear algebra Problem with 3rd derivative

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

> Be the function 
>   $$f(x) = \frac{(x - 1)^3}{37x^6 - 61x^5 + 13x^2 - 74x + 25}.$$
>   Calculate $f'''(1)$.

First year physics grade problem. Linear algebra subject.

Comment: Why is this a linear algebra problem?

Comment: @user1551 well, the set of rational functions in $\Bbb R$ can be considered a vector space of continuum dimensions, and the differential operator is linear, so its third iteration is also linear.

Answer (score 2):

It's $$\frac{6}{37\cdot1^6-61\cdot1^5+13\cdot1^2-74\cdot1+25}=-\frac{1}{10}$$

Comment: @Kenny Lau All time if I need to differentiate the denominator I need to   multiply  it by $0$. See please  better my solution.

Comment: I am amazed. Downvote retracted and upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = 37x^6 - 61x^5 + 13x^2 - 74x + 25$ and differentiate $f(x) \cdot g(x) = (x - 1)^3\,$:

$$
f'(x) \cdot g(x) + f(x)\cdot (\dots) \;=\; 3(x-1)^2
$$

Since $f(1)=0\,$, and given that $g(1) \ne 0\,$, it follows that $f'(1)=0\,$. Differentiating again:.

$$
f''(x) \cdot g(x) + f'(x)\cdot (\dots)+f(x)\cdot(\dots) \;=\; 6(x-1)
$$

Since $f'(1)=f(1)=0\,$ it follows that $f''(1)=0\,$. Finally:

$$
f'''(x) \cdot g(x) + f''(x)\cdot (\dots) + f'(x)\cdot (\dots)+f(x)\cdot(\dots) \;=\; 6
$$

Since $f''(1)=f'(1)=f(1)=0\,$ it follows that $\displaystyle f'''(1)=\frac{6}{g(1)}\,$.